# How to follow redirect in grequests?

Tags: python, grequests

How to follow redirect in grequests ?

In requests library we can simply use : `r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)` to allow redirect .

is there anything in grequests ?

i have checked https://pypi.org/project/grequests/ but did not found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You could follow the same pattern for `grequests`. If you look at the `grequests` source code you could see that the `send` method itself delegating the call to the actual [`request.Session().request`](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/eaab47f033cae3bd443abb6707dfc30ae3482c36/requests/sessions.py#L466) method. This means that you can simply do

```
rs = grequests.get(u, allow_redirects=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
grequests.get(u, allow_redirects=True)
```

would do , according to its source code, all parameters are passed to the session.request 
https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests/blob/master/grequests.py#L71

Maybe you should try https://github.com/requests/requests-threads